# Working with different directories in the same Git respository

Tags: git, version-control, github

I am working on a project involving Android and a remote MySQL DB interacting through PHP.
While I have my android files in a directory and uploaded to Github repository, my PHP files are located in the htdocs of my Apache installation folder.

As both parts -the Android files and the PHP ones- are part of the same directory, I was wondering whether it's possible to work with Git + Github, having all of these files in the same repository but when pushing/committing/checking out all these files, each one going to its right directory?

Best regards and thanks!

Comment: Not sure what you are using, but isn't it possible to create a symbolic link in your htdocs to the php part of the repository?

Comment: Could you pu both parts into different subdirectories of your repository ~/myrepo and then symlink from ~/htdocs and ~/android to ~/myrepo/htdocs and ~/myrepo/android?

Comment: @Ikke: you beat me by 7 seconds ;-)

Comment: @Ikke I tried to create a shortcut (I'm in Windows 7) and it doesn't work, basically because my Android application cannot interact with the .php file shortcut -the user gets the header instead of the actual PHP response.

Comment: use [mklink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link) to create a symbolic link under ntfs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may be able to do this with git-new-workdir. I've never used it, but I found this site which can probably help you get started:

http://kohei.us/2010/11/16/working-with-a-branch-using-git-new-workdir/

Comment: I've never worked in my life with such but I'll have to give it a try. Nevertheless, I think this could probably be easier as this is not a very uncommon feature which most of the developer would like to have. Thanks a lot!